# cpan install then cpan force install produces two copies

Tags: perl, cpan

Context: Windows 7.  Perl: Strawberry version 5.20

Prologue: I installed Mail::Sender using the install command from the cpan shell.  It asked me if I wanted to enter default values.  I said Yes but then I just put in blank for all the values.  What I really wanted was to have said No.  When the installation was done, I started all over.  But in order to make anything happen, I had to use force install.  This time I answered No to the default values question.  The resulting installation functions satisfactorily.  But, looking in the folder \Strawberry\cpan\build\Mail-Sender\blib\lib I find two subdirectories for the Mail module, apparently corresponding to my two installation attempts.

Question: can I safely delete the older of these two Mail module directories?

Answer (score 3):

The `cpan\build` is just `cpan`'s temporary workspace. Its contents can be safely deleted.

`cpan`'s setting `build_cache` limits the size of this directory. Setting it to zero clears that directory every time `cpan` is started and/or every time you start installing a module.

---

The first thing `cpan` after obtaining the distribution tarball is to unzip it into a new unique subdirectory of `cpan\build`<sup>[1]</sup>.

After doing a bit a prep work, the installation process will install the distribution into a temporary subdirectory named `blib`<sup>[2]</sup>. The tests will be run using the modules installed in `blib`. If the tests pass, the files in `blib` are copied to their final location.

---

1. Existing build directories can be reused if `cpan`'s `build_dir_reuse` setting is true. (I recommend against that; it causes problem, without any upside.) Even then, deleting the build directories isn't a problem.
2. This is the what installed based on ExtUtils::MakeMaker or Module::Build installers do. Other installers may behave differently.